# didChaneDependencies not working / flutter

Tags: flutter, overriding

Here is code from one of the screens where I'm trying to use didChaneDependencies:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shop/screens/cart_screen.dart';

import '../widgets/products_grid.dart';
import '../widgets/badge.dart';
import '../widgets/app_drawer.dart';

import '../providers/products.dart';
import '../providers/cart.dart';

enum FilterOptions {
  Favorites,
  All,
}

class ProductsOverviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductsOverviewScreenState createState() => _ProductsOverviewScreenState();
}

class _ProductsOverviewScreenState extends State<ProductsOverviewScreen> {
  var _showOnlyFavorite = false;
  var _isInit = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    print('initState');
    super.initState();
  }
@override
  void didChaneDependencies() {
 print('didChaneDependencies');
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Problem is that it does not fires up.
And the compiler highlights it with the following message:

> The method doesn't override an inherited method. Try updating this
> class to match the superclass, or removing the override annotation.

I did try remove the @override , but that did not fixed the problem, I cannot see
`print('didChaneDependencies');` in the debugger.

Comment: Always check your spelling, read your code well too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the spelling of the function name, You are missing a G in the `didChangeDependencies` function name

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() { 
   ....
```

Comment: Damn what a noob am I :))))) Thnx a lot Mate!

Comment: interesting... 